# boost::program_options: how to get the application name?

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

Using Boost Program Options, how do you get the string equivalent of argv[0]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  This may be because the program name could also legally be used as an option name.

The command line parser code explicitly skips the relevant `argv` member:

```
template<class charT>
basic_command_line_parser<charT>::
basic_command_line_parser(int argc, charT* argv[])
: detail::cmdline(
    // Explicit template arguments are required by gcc 3.3.1 
    // (at least mingw version), and do no harm on other compilers.
    to_internal(detail::make_vector<charT, charT**>(argv+1, argv+argc+!argc)))
{}
```